# Extracting paths from text file using python

Tags: python

I have a huge text file which contains different paths. I have to extract the paths that contains .o files. I am doing so but 1st path is not getting extracted. I need to make a generalized code to extract this type of files
Piece of file is as shown below

---------- .note sections ----------

Section .note, section 18652:

00000000 type: unknown entry type

0000000c name: Altium

00000014 desc: ltc

00000018 type: unknown entry type

00000024 name: Altium

0000002c desc: TASKING VX-toolset for TriCore: object linker v6.0r1 Build 277

0000006c     : SN 07689630

00000078 type: unknown entry type

00000084 name: Altium

0000008c desc: ltc -o C:\00_SIVA\TRW\SANDBOX\DAIMLER_MRAV3_V1.1149\BUILD\TriCore

000000ce     : _MM_APP\TriCore_MM_APP.out -dC:\00_Siva\trw\sandbox\Daimler_MRAv3

0000010f     : _v1.1149\MainMicro\Application\Os\LinkerCmd\Source\Linker.lsl

0000014d     : --error-limit=99999 -OCLtxY --output=C:\00_SIVA\TRW\SANDBOX\DAIML

0000018e     : ER_MRAV3_V1.1149\BUILD\TriCore_MM_APP\TriCore_MM_APP.sre:SREC:4 -

000001cf     : MC:\00_SIVA\TRW\SANDBOX\DAIMLER_MRAV3_V1.1149\BUILD\TriCore_MM_AP

00000210     : P\TriCore_MM_APP.mapxml:XML --optimize=-delete-unreferenced-secti

00000251     : ons,-first-fit-decreasing,+copytable-compression,+delete-duplicat

00000292     : e-code,-delete-duplicate-data --map-file=C:\00_SIVA\TRW\SANDBOX\D

000002d3     : AIMLER_MRAV3_V1.1149\BUILD\TriCore_MM_APP\TriCore_MM_APP.map

00000310     : --map-file --user-provided-initialization-code C:\00_SIVA\TRW\SAN

00000351     : DBOX\DAIMLER_MRAV3_V1.1149\MainMicro\Application\SafeTLib\SBST\SB

00000392     : ST_Kernel_CoreTest.o C:\00_SIVA\TRW\SANDBOX\DAIMLER_MRAV3_V1.1149

000003d3     : \MainMicro\Application\SafeTLib\SBST\SBST_Kernel_ISG.o C:\00_SIVA

00000414     : \TRW\SANDBOX\DAIMLER_MRAV3_V1.1149\MainMicro\Application\SafeTLib

00000455     : \SBST\SBST_Kernel_TestCode.o C:\00_SIVA\TRW\SANDBOX\DAIMLER_MRAV3

00000496     : _V1.1149\MainMicro\Application\SafeTLib\SBST\SBST_RelocTable.o

```
import re

ftemp = open(r'D:/temp.txt','w+')
ftest = open(r'D:/test123.txt','w+')
infile = open(r'D:/HLDUMPTC_of_ELF_file.txt','r')
data = infile.readlines()
#print(type(data))
#print(len(data))

actual_data = []
for i in data:
    a = i.rstrip('\n')
    colon_split = a.split(':',1)   
    if(len(colon_split) > 1):
        fdata=colon_split[1].lstrip()
        actual_data.append(fdata)
        #actual_data.append(colon_split[1])


ftemp.writelines(actual_data)
ftemp.close()
infile.close()

ftemp = open(r'D:/temp.txt','r')
temp_data = ftemp.readlines()
#print(type(temp_data))

temp_data1 = [x.lstrip(' ') for x in temp_data]
temp_data2 = [x.rstrip(' ') for x in temp_data1]

line = ''.join(temp_data2)
#print(type(line))
#print(len(line))

nameslist = line.split('.o')
#print(type(nameslist))
#ftest.writelines(nameslist)
#sbreak

ogslist=[]
ogscount = 0

for x in nameslist:
    new = x + '.o'
    newstr1 = new.lstrip(' ')
    newstr = newstr1.replace('. o','.o')
    ogstest = '-Ogs -o' in newstr
    srctest = '.src' in newstr
    if(ogstest == True):
        ogslist.append(newstr)
        ogscount += 1
        continue
    if(srctest == True):
        continue

    if(re.search('^[A-Z][:]',newstr)):

        ftest.write(newstr)
        ftest.write("\n")


#print(ogslist)

for a in ogslist:
    res_spl = a.split('-Ogs -o')
    file1 = res_spl[1].lstrip(' ')
    file = file1.rstrip(' ')
    oend = re.search('.o$',file)
    if(oend == True):
        ftest.write(file)
        ftest.write("\n")

ftest.close()
ftemp.close()

### Final Formatting

fcheck = open(r'D:/test123.txt','r')
ffinal = open(r'D:/out.txt','w+')

check_data = fcheck.readlines()

for s in check_data:
    ccnt = s.count('.o')
    if(ccnt > 1):
        final_split = s.split('.o')
        if(len(final_split) > 0):
            for k in final_split:
                final = k + '.o'
                ffinal.write(final)
                ffinal.write("\n")
    else:
        ffinal.write(s)
        ffinal.write("\n")

ffinal.close()
fcheck.close()
```

OUTPUT:
C:\00_SIVA\TRW\SANDBOX\DAIMLER_MRAV3_V1.1149\MainMicro\Application\SafeTLib\SBST\SBST_Kernel_ISG.o

C:\00_SIVA\TRW\SANDBOX\DAIMLER_MRAV3_V1.1149\MainMicro\Application\SafeTLib\SBST\SBST_Kernel_TestCode.o

C:\00_SIVA\TRW\SANDBOX\DAIMLER_MRAV3_V1.1149\MainMicro\Application\SafeTLib\SBST\SBST_RelocTable.o

C:\00_SIVA\TRW\SANDBOX\DAIMLER_MRAV3_V1.1149\MainMicro\Application\SafeTLib\SBST\SBST_TC16E_TestCode.o

C:\00_SIVA\TRW\SANDBOX\DAIMLER_MRAV3_V1.1149\MainMicro\Application\SafeTLib\SBST\SBST_TC16P_CoreTest.o

C:\00_SIVA\TRW\SANDBOX\DAIMLER_MRAV3_V1.1149\MainMicro\Application\SafeTLib\SBST\SBST_TC16P_ISG.o

But the output is missing the 1st path i.e C:\00_SIVA\TRW\SANDBOX\DAIMLER_MRAV3_V1.1149\MainMicro\Application\SafeTLib\SBST\SBST_Kernel_CoreTest.o

Comment: Is there a unique pattern for your file path? Like file path always occurs at the end of the line? or at a specific column in the line? Paste some content of your file which includes .o files with proper indentation.

Comment: No, Actually there are some addresses at the left. And the paths are in continue format. The paths starts from C: or D: or any capital Alphabet and will end with file_name.o @RajuPitta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the the path can be anywhere but separated by spaces with other words:

```
with open("test.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        for word in line.split(" "):
            if re.search("^.*\.o$", word):
                print (word.strip())
```

Comment: This code is almost working. Thank you very much sir. @Raju Pitta